# HTML underline <u></u> markups not working in RDLC report

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, rdlc

I have an RDLC report which needs to show HTML formatting in generated report. It works fine when we create placeholder and set markup type to "HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles. But still it does not show the "`<u> Underline Text </u>`" as underlined text. Rest of the markups work fine. Can anybody help me out to fix this underline text problem?

Comment: Use CSS, `text-decoration: underline`

Comment: @Raptor : text-decoration:underline didn't work. Otherwise why would I have asked this question anyway.

Comment: I am displaying text entered in cleditor to rdlc report. It sets style to text-decoration:underline when text is underlined. It doesn't add <u> tag as it is deprecated now. Is there any way I can force it to use <u> tag instead.

Comment: *didn't work* is NOT a valid problem description. Clarify your question, provide code examples, JSFiddle as well

Answer (score 0):

Inside `<Style>` insert:

```
<TextDecoration>Underline</TextDecoration>
```